# The earlier an idea in the Torah is presented, the more primary it is

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, tanach

I remember hearing or reading once that ideas/lessons taught early on in the Torah (she'biksav), say in Be'reishis, are more primary ideas than those that are presented later on.

My question is, does anyone have a source for this idea?
(It might have been said in the name of Rav Tzadok HaKohen, I don't remember.)

Comment: What does it mean for an idea to be "more primary"?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I was hoping that my question would ring a bell for someone and that I could look up the idea in the/a original source.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're thinking of:

Rabbi *Moshe* Shapiro's book ממעמקים, at the start of one of the essays on פרשת לך־לך, indicates that there's a tradition in the name of the [*G'ra*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon), and it's well accepted, that the first time something appears in the Torah tells us something of its true nature. Thus, he cites for example from [*Bava Kama* 55](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2898), seeing the letter *tes* in a dream is good omen, because the first time *tes* appears in the Torah is in the word "*tov*" ("good").

Answer (score 1):

There might be a big difference between "ideas" and "lessons", but perhaps you are referring to the assumption that the *g'mara* gives preference to earlier *p'sukim* over later ones when choosing prooftexts.

For example, *Tosafos* assumes that a *pasuk* from *Vayikra* should have been preferred over one from *Yirmiyahu* by default in the [discussion of monetary transaction sources on *Kidushin 2*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=2b&format=pdf).

> **והא דלא מייתי קנין שנכתב בתורה**
>    מכסף מקנתו (ויקרא כה) משום דבעי לאתויי קנין לשדה

Another possible example of this (once again, exemplified by its absence/exclusion) is that Rava should have preferred to teach how to interpret the Torah's legal round numbers (as in "40" == 39) from a *pasuk* in *Vayikra* rather than the one in *D'varim* that he chose. See for example [this sheet](http://ohr.edu/yomi/yomi080.pdf).